# How to get tabular type of answer key instead of OMR template type output from Auto Multiple choice?

Tags: exam, auto-multiple-choice, mcexam

How do i obtain the answer in answer key table instead of OMR Sheet type in Auto-Multiple-Choice ?

Present

[image]

Required output

[image]

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To change the answer key into a simple table you can modify the internal commands used for printing the answers for each question.

Specifically, the internal command `\AMC@answerBox@` prints the list of answers for a question. You can modify this command by checking if the answer is correct, and only printing it in that case. The code for checking if the current answer is the correct answer can be copied from other internal commands, which is essentially an if-statement to see if the second argument of the command is equal to the internal command `\AMC@checkedbox`. The modified command is as follows:

```
\renewcommand\AMC@answerBox@[4]{%
\ifAMC@catalog%
    \AMC@logchar{#1}{#4}%
\fi%
\ifx #2\AMC@checkedbox \AMCchoiceLabelFormat{#1}\fi%
}
```

Then there is the internal command `\AMCformAnswerA` that adds horizontal space between the answers. If you don't want to print incorrect answers then this horizontal space should also be removed. Simplifying this command results in:

```
\def\AMCformAnswerA#1{\addtocounter{AMC@ncase}{1}#1}
```

Full MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage[separateanswersheet,answers,noshuffle]{automultiplechoice}
\AMCboxStyle{shape=oval}

\begin{document}
\AMCtext{draft}{}
\AMCtext{message}{}
\begin{question}{prez} first \begin{choices}\correctchoice{a1}\wrongchoice{a2}\wrongchoice{a3}\wrongchoice{a4}\end{choices}\end{question}
\begin{question}{prez} second \begin{choices}\wrongchoice{a1}\wrongchoice{a2}\correctchoice{a3}\wrongchoice{a4}\end{choices}\end{question}
\begin{question}{prez} third \begin{choices}\wrongchoice{a1}\wrongchoice{a2}\correctchoice{a3}\wrongchoice{a4}\end{choices}\end{question}
\begin{question}{prez} fourth \begin{choices}\wrongchoice{a1}\wrongchoice{a2}\correctchoice{a3}\wrongchoice{a4}\end{choices}\end{question}
\begin{question}{prez} fifth \begin{choices}\wrongchoice{a1}\wrongchoice{a2}\wrongchoice{a3}\correctchoice{a4}\end{choices}\end{question}
\begin{question}{prez} sixth \begin{choices}\correctchoice{a1}\wrongchoice{a2}\wrongchoice{a3}\wrongchoice{a4}\end{choices}\end{question}
\begin{question}{prez} seventh \begin{choices}\correctchoice{a1}\wrongchoice{a2}\wrongchoice{a3}\wrongchoice{a4}\end{choices}\end{question}
\begin{question}{prez} eighth \begin{choices}\wrongchoice{a1}\correctchoice{a2}\wrongchoice{a3}\wrongchoice{a4}\end{choices}\end{question}
\begin{question}{prez} ninth \begin{choices}\wrongchoice{a1}\correctchoice{a2}\wrongchoice{a3}\wrongchoice{a4}\end{choices}\end{question}
\begin{question}{prez} tenth \begin{choices}\wrongchoice{a1}\wrongchoice{a2}\wrongchoice{a3}\correctchoice{a4}\end{choices}\end{question}
\begin{question}{prez} eleventh \begin{choices}\wrongchoice{a1}\wrongchoice{a2}\correctchoice{a3}\wrongchoice{a4}\end{choices}\end{question}
\begin{question}{prez} twelfth \begin{choices}\correctchoice{a1}\wrongchoice{a2}\wrongchoice{a3}\wrongchoice{a4}\end{choices}\end{question}
\begin{question}{prez} thirteenth \begin{choices}\correctchoice{a1}\wrongchoice{a2}\wrongchoice{a3}\wrongchoice{a4}\end{choices}\end{question}
\begin{question}{prez} fourteenth \begin{choices}\wrongchoice{a1}\wrongchoice{a2}\correctchoice{a3}\wrongchoice{a4}\end{choices}\end{question}
\begin{question}{prez} fifteenth \begin{choices}\wrongchoice{a1}\wrongchoice{a2}\correctchoice{a3}\wrongchoice{a4}\end{choices}\end{question}
\makeatletter
\def\AMCformQuestion#1{#1.}
\def\AMCformAnswerA#1{\addtocounter{AMC@ncase}{1}#1}
\renewcommand\AMC@answerBox@[4]{%
\ifAMC@catalog%
    \AMC@logchar{#1}{#4}%
\fi%
\ifx #2\AMC@checkedbox \AMCchoiceLabelFormat{#1}\fi%
}
\makeatother

\hrule
\vspace{5mm}
{\Large ANSWER KEY}
\AMCformBegin
\begin{multicols}{3}
\AMCform
\end{multicols}

\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

Remark: this kind of modifications are changing the original implementation of the answer key significantly. There may be side effects, i.e., other parts of the code that don't work correctly anymore.

Comment: Hi, your MWE is giving me an error

` ! Undefined control sequence.`
`\AMC@answerBox@ #1#2#3#4->\ifAMC@catalog `
`\AMC@logchar {#1}{#4}\fi \ifx #2\AM...`
`l.41 \AMCform `.    also it gives another error saying too many ifs

Comment: @Aman did you try the MWE exactly as given without modifications, or did you just copy the command definition in your real document?

Comment: i copied and pasted your MWE as it is in a separate file.

Comment: @Aman maybe the version of AMC is different. I used the Ubuntu distribution version (`apt install auto-multiple-choice`) which installs the LaTeX package `AMC version: 2018/12/29 v1.4.0 r:c6041a1`, so probably not the newest. Which version do you use?

Comment: @Aman In any case, if the error is around `\ifAMC@catalog` then you could try removing those three lines (so the whole `\ifAMC@catalog% \AMC@logchar{#1}{#4}% \fi%` part) and see if it works then.

Comment: Hey, sorry for the late response. I removed the three lined that you mentioned. Now the numberings are correct, however the answey key is not being printed. ie. [sample](https://imgur.com/a/ANLpB9W) 
I feel we are close here, only perhaps some variables were redefined in new version. What does AMC@catalog and AMC@logchar do? perhaps i can see what are the present equivalent of them.

Comment: @Aman I just downloaded v1.5.0 of AMC which is the most recent that I could find (dated February 12, 2021) and with that version the MWE runs without problems. So now I'm wondering which version you have, maybe if I try that version as well then I can reproduce the problem and hopefully solve it.

Comment: thats weird, i had to change the question reference "prez" to unique ones before even that worked. i am on MacOS and the amc version is (1.4.0+git2020-03-30). See if this helps.

Comment: Hi, so you solution finally worked. I simply changed the automultiplechoice.sty file to the latest one and it magically worked. I will mention that i changed the unique reference to each question, but otherwise it worked perfectly. Thanks!